# R script to fetch pathway from KEGG without using any package

Tags: r

I am creating an R package for text mining, and i want to add a function in the package to get the list of pathways from KEGG. I am able to fetch the pathways from wikipathways but unable to get from KEGG. Please suggest me how can i fetch the pathway from KEGG without any package like NBCI2R nd other, i want to make my own function so please help me.

thank you

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? In the current form, only person with specific knowledge can answer it. If you include more information, us generalists would also be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Before proceeding with this answer I **strongly** encourage you to read http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/legal.html. KEGG is only free for academic use and you need a proper license to provide an API/Library for the services. So most probably you want a non-anonymous access to ftp://ftp.genome.jp/ for which such a license is required.

However, concerning your actual question you find a flat file of all pathways under http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=br08901.keg&format=htext. Just download and parse it:

```
lines <- readLines(
  "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=br08901.keg&format=htext" )
pathways <- do.call(
   rbind,
   str_split( grep( "^[ABCD]\\s+\\d{5}\\s+.*?$", lines, value=TRUE ), "\\s{2,}" )
)
pathways <- as.data.frame( pathways )[-1]
colnames( pathways )  <- c( "ID", "Name" )

head(pathways)

     ID                                         Name
1 01100                           Metabolic pathways
2 01110        Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites
3 01120 Microbial metabolism in diverse environments
4 00010                 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
5 00020                    Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)
6 00030                    Pentose phosphate pathway
```

Note that this also may be only done for not commercial purpose. However, the copyright does not state if a non-browser software may visit the website for non commercial use. So better you don't try this too extensively without having contacted them.

Comment: thnkew for your help, this is really useful for me, but here i need something else, i actualy wanna fetch the name and link of pathway by gene name. so i just provide the name of gene an it will return  me a list of pathways for that gene as well link to those pathways..... smethng quite similar to GetPathways() of NCBI2R R package.

Comment: @Jyoti as a I said, you most probably want access to ftp://ftp.genome.jp/. After registering you'll find their a bunch files. Probably you are interested in the `.*kgml` files which can be easily parsed using R's `XML`package.

Comment: sir I will be very thankful to you for helping me in creating my package, there is one another query i wanna ask, actually i have abstracts from the pubmed but i wanna fetch the conclusion part form them, so is there any function by which  i can fetch the conclusions of all abstracts......

Comment: @Jyoti I'm afraid that I am not experienced enough with Pubmed to answer this. I know that they have a SOAP API which might behelpful. Please keep in mindthat every Q on SO should cover one topic at a time. So you may want to adk this in a seperate Question. And if this question is answered it'd be nice if you accept the answer by klicking the check mark.